# How to operate unique with “with” operator?

Tags: unique, system-verilog

I have faced a strange (from my point of view) behavior of combination of the `unique` method called for a fixed array with the `with` clause.

```
module tb;
    int array[9] = '{4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 1, 6, 3, 1};
    int res[$];
  
    initial begin    
        res = array.unique(x) with (x <= 3);
        $display ("unique       : %p", res);
    end
endmodule
```

I've expected to get the queue `{2,1,3}`, but instead I got `{4,2}`.

I can't understand why there is a one at index 0 and why are 2 and 3 missing from the result?

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain the result you were getting.

The `with` clause of the `unique` method defines the expression used to determine *uniqueness*. It will delete all but one arbitrary element from the set of elements having matching expressions.

Since you chose an expression having a result of 1'b0 or 1'b1, it chose one out of the four elements (2, 1, 3, 1) where `x <= 3` was true (2), and one out of the five elements (4, 7, 5, 7, 6) where it was false (4).

You are trying to combine the `find` method with the `unique` method in a single operation. It doesn't work that way. You have to do it in two separate operations:

```
module tb;
    int array[9] = '{4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 1, 6, 3, 1};
    int res[$];
  
    initial begin    
        res = array.find(x) with (x <= 3);
        res = res.unique;
        $display ("unique       : %p", res);
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply dave_59. I understood to choose one each from an array separated by true and false by with clause. By the way, one question is why 2 is chosen in true and 4 is chosen in false? Is there a particular reason for choosing it?
What I'm wondering is that {2,1,3} should be selected for true and {4,7,5,6} for false because unique items should be selected.

Comment: The choice is arbitrary&mdash;it depends on the implementation. {1,7} is also a possible result. I suggest trying `array.unique(x) with (x % 3);` and looking at the result.